# WPF DataGrid: how to disable selection / focus on a particular DataGridRow?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus, selection

I want that when user press down / up, keyboard focus skips particular rows and jumps beyound them.
I have tried just set `Focusable = false` (on every descendant), in that case focus does not go in that row but it does not go beyond them too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM you could use DataGrid InputBindings to handle up and down arrow keys and set SelectedDataGridItem however you like -

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridItems}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataGridItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=ChangeSelectedItemCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="ArrowDown"
                        Key="Down"/>
            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=ChangeSelectedItemCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="ArrowUp"
                        Key="Up"/>
        </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    </DataGrid>
```